# Can't format external HDD after removing it from computer

Tags: partitioning, external-hdd, format

Connected my old HDD with usb dock to my computer after migrating to SSD. I was dual booting on that HDD now I want to use it as my storage disk. Yet it has 9 partition connected with Windows or Ubuntu. Gparted was able to delete some of them but some are not allowed to turn into unallocated space. There is a key symbol next to those. I can access every disk so it seems healthy but can't format and converge all of them to one partition. Here is how it seems:

PS: I don't want to preserve any data.

Partition Table for my external HDD

[image: picture1]

Comment: Since you're on Linux right now have you tried to unmount those partitions showing still a mount-point? You can do that in terminal if needed with `sudo umount <mount-point>`, or with right clicking the entries in your partition list.

Comment: Yeah it worked out after manually mounting all of them. I created new partition table and parameter error gone. Thanks!

Comment: O.k. then let me add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can read of your screen-shot the partitions are still mounted in your Linux, open a terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and unmount them with issuing the following command for each partition which still shows a mount-point:

```
sudo umount <mount-point>
```

Or as alternative you can right click their entries in the partition list and select unmount.